# AWS API Gateway Custom Authorization header case sensitivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

AWS API Gateway provides [an option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) to use custom authorization via Lambda function. In this approach, user is expected to a configure a custom header name (Example: Auuthorization or Auth). This header value be extracted by Gateway and passed on to Lambda Event.

However, Gateway is searching for incoming headers case sensitively.  I.e if user specifies the header as **authorization** instead of **Authorization**, Gateway returns 401. Why does this search case sensitively when http protocol states that headers can be case insensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Yep this is a known issue with the customer authorizer, and also the header mapping functionality in API Gateway. Header matches are case sensitive, which as you stated is against the spec. I don't have an ETA for fixing this but it is a known issue that we would like to fix.</strike>

**Edit: This should now be resolved. The custom authorizer header match is case insensitive.**

Comment: Seems to be case-sensitive to me.  Using a REQUEST authorizer with 'Authorization" header defined as the Idenitity source (defined via cloudformation/sam).

Comment: Defining 'Headers' as 'Authorization': https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-lambdarequestauthorizationidentity.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you've probably got `method.request.header.Authorization` in the "identity token source" field and not `method.request.header.authorization` (see image attached). Perhaps its not a matter of AWS not following the header standard, but rather it matching what you've told it to look for...

[image: Check out this image for header matching settings]
<sub>(source: [amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/images/custom-auth-create-authorizer.png))</sub>

Wonder if you could use a case insensitive regex like you can in the other header request/response matching fields that API gateway uses. Maybe something like `/(?i)authorization/`. (pure speculation)

see also:

[blog post on custom authorizers in api gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/)

Comment: Bear in mind that case-insensitivity means that also auTHoriZatioN should be treated and authorization.